# what is this "it <= ' '" in trim string function mean here

Tags: android, kotlin, trim

I have this Java code to trim a string

```
String title = titleEt.getText().toString().trim();
```

When I convert to kotlin, I expect this should be the kotlin code to trim the leading and trailing spaces.

```
val title = titleEt.text.toString().trim()
```

However, the IDE generates this code

```
val title = titleEt.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' }
```

What is this { it <= ' ' } here? Is it any char less and than ' '?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Java's [`String#trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) removes all codepoints between `'\u0000'` (NUL) and `'\u0020'` (SPACE) from the start and end of the string.

Kotlin's [`CharSequence.trim()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/trim.html) removes only leading and trailing whitespace by default (characters matching [`Char.isWhitespace`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/is-whitespace.html), which is [`Character#isWhitespace(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(char))). For the same behavior as Java, the IDE generated a predicate that matches the same characters that Java would have trimmed.

These characters include ASCII whitespace, but also include control characters.

```
'\u0000' ␀ ('\0')
'\u0001' ␁
'\u0002' ␂
'\u0003' ␃
'\u0004' ␄
'\u0005' ␅
'\u0006' ␆
'\u0007' ␇ ('\a')
'\u0008' ␈ ('\b')
'\u0009' ␉ ('\t')
'\u000A' ␊ ('\n')
'\u000B' ␋ ('\v')
'\u000C' ␌ ('\f')
'\u000D' ␍ ('\r')
'\u000E' ␎
'\u000F' ␏
'\u0010' ␐
'\u0011' ␑
'\u0012' ␒
'\u0013' ␓
'\u0014' ␔
'\u0015' ␕
'\u0016' ␖
'\u0017' ␗
'\u0018' ␘
'\u0019' ␙
'\u001A' ␚
'\u001B' ␛
'\u001C' ␜
'\u001D' ␝
'\u001E' ␞
'\u001F' ␟
'\u0020' ␠ (' ')
```

Answer (score 4):

trim function in kotlin allows a predicate so trim in java code (removes the white spaces) is the same as `.trim { it <= ' ' }` 
You can use `.trim()` in kotlin too

Comment: Do you mind to explain that using other words? I still couldn't understand it

Comment: When you convert from Java to Kotlin the plugin translate java's trim()  to .trim{ it <=' '}  because kotlin's trim allows a predicate and in this case the predicate is a white space

Answer (score 3):

It is comparing the ASCII of each char which ' ' (space). If the ASCII of the character is less than or equal to that of the ASCII of ' ' (space), it is removed.

If you look at the [ASCII table](http://ascii.cl/), the symbols below space ( ASCII 32) are non-printable control characters. So all the printable characters other than space are above the ASCII of space (which is 32). So if the characters whose ASCII is lesser than or equal to that of ' ' (space) are removed, we will get the remaining String without leading and trailing whitespace.

This is how the Java's `trim()` works. Nevertheless, you can just use `trim()` also in Kotlin:

```
titleEt.text.toString().trim()
```

Answer (score 2):

See the [`String.trim`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/trim.html) overload that takes a `predicate`. It is said to trim the leading and trailing characters off the string which match the predicate. In your case, it will trim the characters that are less than or equal to `' '` (the whitespace).

This is exactly how [`java.lang.String#trim`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) works.